# Parallel execution for multiple tags using cucumber

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, cucumber, parallel-execution

I want to parallely execute the scenarios groupwise.how can I achieve it in cucumber?like thread 1 should execute only smoke scenario thread 2 should execute regression etc

I tried passing different tags in the cucumber options section and increase thread count based number of tags but it's not working

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.